# Is Dr. Jackson a crutch for the writers?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Aside from being a convenient crutch for the writers, why is Dr. Jackson a member of the most elite of the Stargate teams, SG-1? He has no military training, a weak personality, and, not to mention he was on the alien planet of Abydos for quite a many years. He could have been corrupted, brainwashed, or possibly even infected by some alien pathogen. Plus he has bad allergies, which aren't very conducive for the type of intense missions that SG-1 must go on.

Are there any in-universe or canonical reasons why he's a member of SG-1? Or is he more-or-less the "universal translator" of SG-1?

Comment: So, my answer spans most of the question body, but I have no idea what you mean by "crutch" in the question title.  Can you expand on that, or give examples?

Comment: Crutch, as in something to lean on when they need to work around time/budget/plot limitations... like the universal translator in star trek

Comment: I've seen little evidence of a weak personality.  Quite the contrary, he had a controversial idea and stuck with it, even when it destroyed his career.  People with weak personalities don't do that.  Honestly, this looks like you're just trying to cover your tail in the face of the accusations of racism.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From "Children of the Gods, Part 2":

> *Hammond*:  "Then who's coming through the Stargate?"
>   *Jackson*: "Gods..."
>   *Hammond*: "What?"
>   *Jackson*: "Not as in God god.  Ra played a god, the sun god, he
>   borrowed the religion and culture of the ancient Egyptians he brought
>   through the Gate, and then he used it to enslave them, so see, he
>   wanted the people of Abydos to believe he was the only one."

Jackson rambles on a bit more to realize that others of Ra's species can do the same thing as Ra:  Take over others' bodies.  Combined with his knowledge of ancient cultures that these aliens have copied, plus any myths or stories he's learned while on Abydos, Jackson is the *most* qualified person to go.  And if that's not enough, a moment later Hammond mentions one of the purposes of these teams is something Jackson (by understanding the aliens' language and culture) could do better than anyone else on the teams at the time (emphasis mine):

> *Hammond*:  "However, the president of the United States happens to
>   agree with you.  In the event your theories pan out, he has ordered
>   the formation of nine teams, whose duties will be to perform
>   reconnaissance, determine threats, and if possible to **make peaceful
>   contact** with the people of these worlds."

Finally, Hammond wanted Jackson to stay on as a consultant to all the teams, but Jackson demanded he be included in SG-1, essentially giving an ultimatum:  He would not cooperate unless he was on SG-1.  So Hammond had a decision to make, either lose Jackson's expertise entirely, or let him join SG-1.  Hammond chose the latter.

Comment: Ah wonderful, I forgot about the ultimatum!

Comment: +1 for "make peaceful contact". Historically, as a trope of sci-fi television and film, the last thing any military group is capable of doing is make peaceful contact with anyone.

Answer (score 5):

He was chosen by Catherine Langford in the movie to help decode the symbols. From there he got on the first mission to Abydos by talking his way on to the team by saying he's the only one that could get them home, or that is why he was chosen to go on that first mission. In *SG-1* when the Goa'uld attack the first time, Jack goes sends a message through the Stargate and then Sha're (Jackson's wife) and Skaara are taken and they go on the mission to save them. When they fail and recruit Teal'c, Jackson stays on the team to find/save his wife.

I would suggest you watch the movie *Stargate* (1994) and the first episode of *Stargate SG-1* for more info on why/how this happens.

Comment: I watched both the movie and first episode, and Catherine Langford was *not* military. These are all nice things to do, but nice things shouldn't earn you a spot in the best of the best. The Colonel clearly earned his place, as did Carter. I'm just suggesting that we wouldn't allow the Ancient Aliens guy to be on such a team.

Comment: Doesn't matter your disagreement is subjective first of all. Secondly his expertise in ancient languages and archaeology field makes him a perfect candidate for being there. His attachment to the whole thing is the in-story why they said ok at the end. Just a side note, this site is not about subjective material but in story facts. You already touched on his expertise and I told you why they said 'yes' in story.

Comment: it feels like you're trying to get someone to agree with you that Dr Jackson is a waste of time on this show. Which is not true, his expertise has gotten them out of a lot of situations and has acted as the all important initial diplomat in establishing relations with other worlds. In the real world, this is important when exploring new areas.

Comment: Well seeing that the show is supposed be be based on our real military... and we can look to military rules and regulations of clearance, it's not subjective at all. Consultants don't get to be NASA astronauts, and probably wouldn't go stargating either.

Comment: "Consultants don't get to be NASA astronauts" - Neil Armstrong and Harrison Schmitt both walked on the moon and were _not_ military personell. (Armstrong had a Navy career but had resigned his commission years before becoming an astronaut.) Several of [Astronaut Group 20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Astronaut_Group_20) have no past or active military career. Lots more in-between didn't either.

Comment: There is a specific section of NASA for training civilian scientists to become astronauts.

Answer (score 4):

Jackson has at least 3 invaluable skills that frequently benefit the team, aside from his honorary place as the person who deciphered the Stargate.

1. He knows more about Ancient, Goa'uld, and other alien languages than anyone else alive.
2. He knows about various cultures, which leads them to understanding frequently.
3. He is skilled at talking with shy people, and really connecting with them, far more than anyone else.

While he has had numerous opportunities for being lead astray, his unique skills seem to have overcome any misgivings he had. He is a natural diplomat.

Comment: There is a fourth, but it's not so much a skill as an asset - he isn't military personnel. Whilst it doesn't seem like much, it does mean that he is more likely to stick to his ideals or challenge orders. For example the time Jackson used his civilian status to rescue members of the Tollan from Maybourne - anyone else would've gotten court martialled.

(Compared to Carter, who will put in her two cents, and if O'Neill/Hammond disagree, she wont put up much of a fight. Usually.)

Answer (score -3):

I think evolving into a higher life-form is a qualification.

Comment: He did that long after becoming a member of SG-1 and only because he was a member. It doesn't answer why he would be a member of SG-1 in the first place.